# Move file associations from Visual Studio 2005 to 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

Both Visual Studio 2005 and Visual Studio 2008 is installed on my PC, but when I open a .aspx or .master file from Explorer, it opens in 2005. I would like them to open in 2008.

I could change the file associations manually, but there are quite a lot of file extensions to go through.

Is there an easy way to give all the file associations back to 2008?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe this:
Options -> Environment -> General -> Restore File Associations

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it like this.

First create a text file (assocs) with all your existing settings

```
assoc | findstr -i VisualStudio > assocs
```

Next edit this file change 8.0 to 9.0 in cases like:

> .vbdproj=VisualStudio.vbdproj.8.0 -> .vbdproj=VisualStudio.vbdproj.9.0

Next save this file and run the following command to create a batch file to alter the settings:

```
for /f "tokens=1-10 delims==" %i in (assocs.) do @echo assoc %i=%j >> new_assocs.bat
```

Finally run the batch file:

```
new_assocs.bat
```