# Change Visual Studio Version in run-command(Start -> Run -> devenv)

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have both **VS 2008** and **VS 2010** installed in my PC (Windows XP). Now I try to open **IDE** via **Start -> Run -> devenv** it always open **VS 2008** environment. Is it possible to change this settings ?? That is I do want to open **VS 2010** when I type **devenv** in **Start -> Run**  
Graciously welcoming any help.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

These are the steps for windows 7:

1. Press windows + r to open run window and then write "regedit" to open your PC registry.
2. Then go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` -> `SOFTWARE` -> `Microsoft` -> `Windows` -> `Currentversion` -> `App Paths` -> `devenv.exe`
3. Click on `devenv.exe` and change the value of `default`.

When you open `default` it has value like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe`

You need to change the value to your other installation, maybe `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe`

After completing steps above, when you run `devenv` command it opens vs2010.

Comment: Ahh.. in my case it is not working. I am getting error -"Can not edit - error writing the values new content". I am using Windows 7.

Comment: @GirishK it may be a _permission issue_, have a look on this [link](http://windows7themes.net/windows-7-registry-changes.html)

Comment: @Jith Yupp.. It was permission issue.. Got it solved from admin.. Thanks :)

Comment: @GirishK: It's simple, if you don't have admin rights, you cannot alter the registry keys in HKLM. You need to set them in HKCU ==> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\devenv.exe]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\Common7\\IDE\\devenv.exe"

Comment: You can also add a second devenv, like this:[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\devenv2.exe]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\\Common7\\IDE\\devenv.exe"

Comment: The path for visual studio 2017 is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"

Comment: 2022 compatible (bye x86)! 
`"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"`  

And for the lazy, win10 lets you paste in registry paths instead of all the clicking :D

`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\devenv.exe`

Comment: Seems you could go to settings , apps, default apps and type in .sln and change

Answer (score 4):

I would simply find some Visual studio solution file, right click, properties, change the default version from 2008 to 2010

Comment: I think it was downvoted because it doesn't actually resolve what this question is asking. But it does resolve the problem of files associations to the VS of your choice (which is similar to [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1326506/146513)).

Answer (score 1):

Consider Visual studio 13 is installed at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"

Now if I want to make Visual studio 13 as default rather than having Visual studio 15 as default then change the following

[image]

Press windows + r to open run window and then write "regedit" to open your PC registry.

Then go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -> SOFTWARE -> Microsoft -> Windows -> Currentversion -> App Paths -> devenv.exe