# Error Changing Visual Studio Version in run-command(Start -> Run -> devenv)

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windows-7

I am trying to change the version of Visual studio in run command. I am following the steps given in one of the post : [Change Visual Studio Version in run-command(Start -> Run -> devenv)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880431/change-visual-studio-version-in-run-commandstart-run-devenv)

But I am getting following error - "Can not edit - error writing the values new content".

I am using Windows 7. I dont have admin rights. I think i have "power user" type admin rights.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the error because you do not have permission to edit the registry. Try the follwing:

- Right-click on the key (int this case 'App paths') and click on 'Permissions';
- Select your username, check the option “Full Control” below and click on “OK”:
- Now try the steps from the linked post again

Comment: yaa.. you were right. I dont have permissions to change. And I dint have a permission to check the check box "Full Control". I had to use admin password to get it done. Finally its working now. thanks :)