# Uninstall Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise Completely, as if never installed

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I installed an SSD in my drive to put Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise on, and I named the drive W:

as I wanted to save space, I followed this 2 tutorials on creating symbolic links to try to save some
1: change %TMP% and %TEMP% to DriveLetterYouWantVSin:\Temp
2. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/49055/vs2015-vs2017-ignore-path-selection-during-install.html

I installed VS2017 and everything went fine.
Then I decided I didn't like W: drive letter and wanted to change it to G:. I knew this will be hard so I wanted to uninstall VS2017 and the installer couldn't find it
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmJhg.jpg)

so I went and manually uninstalled VS2017 with IOBIT uninstaller, everything seemed fine, I changed the drive letter to G:, deleted evey symlink I created, deleted every ProgramData\VisualStudio folder I could find, cleared %TEMP% dirs, decided I will not use any symlinks and rerun the installer

but I couldn't change SDK, Shared component, Tools, SDK location and on github it even says that you can only do this once: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/blob/master/docs/install/change-installation-locations.md

> IMPORTANT This location is set with your first installation and cannot be changed later from the installer UI. Instead, you must use command-line parameters to move the download cache.

I fiddled my way around that by creating virtual hard disk, nammed W: so installed thought W: is still present and then installed what I wanted

but I wanted to modify something and I couldn't because I get the same error when trying to uninstall/modify like before
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmJhg.jpg)

so now my question is: How do I get rid of Visual Studio like it never existed, so I can start fresh.

I do not have a restore point unfortunately

Thanks for Anwsering and Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

Well after many hours I was finaly able to get rid of it

I searched for VisualStudio and Visual Studio on my C Drive and deleted everyhing (exept my projects) related to it.

Then I removed everything that had VisualStudio in Registry

and I was able to run the installer and reinstall everything again

although my file types weren't working then so I did what was suggested here: [Visual Studio files association in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46351778/visual-studio-files-association-in-windows)

then also had to had to run theese 2 reg files in the zip: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=00805027711279044602

to fix Extension being bound to VSIX Installer

after that extensions still refused to run I got the same error as some guy here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/25294/tools-extensions-and-updates-gives-error-retrievin.html

so I reran the installer (and it actually detected my VS this time :)) and hit repair (after BSOD (for some reason I got it)) everything worked fine (well almost my VS2015 solutions still lack the icon (but they open just fine))